# I get this error when I want to connect my database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am doing a course on the internet and everything was going well until I had to connect a database. It has not worked for me and I have looked for many solutions but I have 2 days and I do not get anything

**Here the database code**

```
   <?php
   function conectar_bd()
   {
       $servidor = "127.0.0.1";
       $usuario = "jhon28";
       $contraseña = "Elmenor28519";
       $nombrebd = "empresa";
       $conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "jhon28", "Elmenor28519");
       mysqli_select_db($conexion, $nombrebd);
       return $conexion;
    }
    ?>
```

**Here the connection code**

```
<?php
include("basededatos.php");
$conexionbd=conectar_bd();
echo $conexionbd;
mysqli_close ($conexionbd);
?>
```

**Here the error that come to me**

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 4

Comment: `echo $conexionbd;` to `var_dump($conexionbd);` or `print_r($conexionbd)`. Because `$conexionbd` is an object.

Comment: Why would you want to echo out the connection object?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `echo $conexionbd;` or change it to `print_r($conexionbd);`

Comment: Perfect answer who gives downvot??

Comment: i don't know Grant C, I'm new here, i can't

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include("basededatos.php");
$conexionbd=conectar_bd();
print_r($conexionbd); //here you are getting object so you can't use echo use print_r instead
mysqli_close ($conexionbd);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the docs you wont need select_db, you may insert it on the same function like below.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $nombrebd);
```

Therefore, you save one line. Just helping to optimize your code. Refer docs for more information.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should be a comment instead. When you have 50 reputation you can start adding comments with suggestions, but until them we ask you to answer the topic in question.